# Simultaneous editing

Tags: bug, editing

Sometimes I see a question on the main site which I feel could be improved on and when I click the edit button it says something along the lines of "this question is already being edited by someone else" and it won't let me edit (note: I have edit approval rights and can see when there is a pending edit to be approved/rejected - this is different to that).

However, sometimes I am in the middle of an edit and I get notified that someone else has edited the post (not always the OP).

How come that person has not been notified that I am in the middle of editing the post?

Comment: If you start editing roughly at the same time another starts editing (so neither of you gets a notification prior to editing), and they submit their edit first, you will get notified.  Note, however, that the notification of the submission of an edit states that your edit needs to be  more substantial than the one already submitted.  Chances are, if you are doing a relatively thorough edit, your submission may stick.

Comment: @amWhy Thanks, that makes sense, kind of a race condition scenario